# SQL JOIN within a JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm not sure how to ask this question or even how to title it so i'm sorry if it's been asked before.

I've created a join that retrieves all information I need.  Sort of.

It returns the customer ID rather than details of the customer from the customer table:

```
 SELECT o.orderTotal, o.orderID, oc.productID, oc.quantity, oc.price_per, co.customerID
 FROM tblOrders o
 INNER JOIN tblOrderContents oc ON o.orderID = oc.orderID
 INNER JOIN tblCustomerOrders co ON o.orderID = co.orderID
```

my customer table is:

```
 **tblCustomer**
 customerID
 customerName etc...
```

How can I make this query return the actual customer information such as name, address etc.. in the same SQL query, and can I even do that?

Answer (score 2):

Simply make another `join` with `tblCustomer`

```
SELECT o.orderTotal, o.orderID, oc.productID, oc.quantity, oc.price_per, co.customerID, c.customerName
FROM tblOrders o
INNER JOIN tblOrderContents oc ON o.orderID = oc.orderID
INNER JOIN tblCustomerOrders co ON o.orderID = co.orderID
INNER JOIN tblCustomer c on co.customerID = c.customerID
```

Answer (score 2):

By joining the customer table, you have access to any of the fields. So just add the fields you want in the SELECT clause with the additional join:

```
SELECT
    o.orderTotal,
    o.orderID,
    oc.productID,
    oc.quantity,
    oc.price_per,
    co.customerID,
    cu.customerName
FROM
    tblOrders o
INNER JOIN
    tblOrderContents oc ON o.orderID = oc.orderID
INNER JOIN
    tblCustomerOrders co ON o.orderID = co.orderID
INNER JOIN
    tblCustomer cu ON cu.customerID = co.customerID
```

Answer (score 0):

If the information of the customer is in the tblCustomer, you can just left join the result you have from your query with this table.

```
select I.* 
from 
(SELECT o.orderTotal, o.orderID, oc.productID, oc.quantity, oc.price_per, co.customerID
 FROM tblOrders o
 INNER JOIN tblOrderContents oc ON o.orderID = oc.orderID
 INNER JOIN tblCustomerOrders co ON o.orderID = co.orderID) as O left join tblCustomer I on O.customerId=I.customerId
```